# How do you set default checked value on switchery js input tag using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, switchery

I'm trying to set default value for the input tag with switchery plugin using the values from database with ajax, but the checked attribute doesnt update, but the update does work without the plugin, what did i do wrong? 
The HTML table form looks something like this :

```
<table>
<thead>
...
</thead>
<tbody>
    @for($j=1; $j<=10; $j++)
    ...
    <td>
      <label>
        <input id="day1-hours{{$j}}" type="checkbox" data-plugin="switchery">
        <span>Active</span>
      </label>
    </td>
    ...
    @endfor
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the ajax success function :

```
for(let $i=1; $i<=6; $i++){
$.ajax({
... //the POST REQUEST
success:function(data){
    for($j=1; $j<=array.length;$j++){
        if(data[$j-1] == "active"){
             $("#day"+$i+"-hours"+$j).prop("checked",true);

        }else{
             $("#day"+$i+"-hours"+$j).prop("checked",false);                 
        }
     };
   }
 ...
}
```

and the data from the ajax success response should be just "active" and "inactive"

Comment: you need to see it class after setting the `switchery`. Provide: **1)** full `ajax` query with defined variables before, because it's quiet interesting to look at `array` & `$i` variables; **2)** go to F12 and show the picture of key `input` where you wanna change it view; **3)** why does your `input` has `X`&`Y` when you're searching `$i`&`$j`; **4)** what value has `$i`?

Comment: @AksenP the value of X and Y is also looped from database, im not providing all the codes, cause i think its not that relevant in this problem, the codes works as intended on regular checkbox inputs, but it doesnt update when i use switchery,

Comment: however, you need to explain your secret `$i`, `X`, `Y`. Because you're using `CHAR`'s and `NUMBER`'s in ID, if there `0..n` instead of chars, ok, but you present chars.

Comment: If you'll do everything I'm asking then I could help you. I think not the only I will in this case. Your `plugin` changes `input` element, I need to see how. It's possible to see via F12. Provide two states of it: when it's **ON** and when it's **OFF**.

Comment: @AksenP i updated the info

Comment: @AksenP Here's the link to the [switchery](https://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/) documentation,

Comment: ok, I see. Wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code. It works for me.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/switchery/0.8.2/switchery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/switchery/0.8.2/switchery.min.css">

<td>
    <label>
        <input id="dayX-hoursY" type="checkbox" data-plugin="switchery" onclick="ch_label(this)">
        <span>Inactive</span>
    </label> 
</td>
```

```
success:function(){
     for($j=1; $j<=array.length;$j++){
        if(data[$j-1] == "active"){

    var css1 = 'background-color: rgb(100, 189, 99); border-color: rgb(100, 189, 99); box-shadow: rgb(100, 189, 99) 0px 0px 0px 16px inset; transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s, background-color 1.2s ease 0s;';
    var css2 = 'left: 20px; transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0s, left 0.2s ease 0s; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);'; 

             $("#day"+$i+"-hours"+$j).attr('checked',true);
             $("#day"+$i+"-hours"+$j).parent().find('span').eq(0).attr('style', css1);
             $("#day"+$i+"-hours"+$j).parent().find('span').eq(0).find('small').attr('style',css2);
             var init = new Switchery($("#day"+$i+"-hours"+$j));
             $("#day"+$i+"-hours"+$j).prop('checked', true);
             $("#day"+$i+"-hours"+$j).parent().find('span').eq(1).text('Active'); 
        }else{

    var css3 = 'background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset; transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s;';
    var css4 = 'left: 0px; transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0s, left 0.2s ease 0s;'; 

             $("#day"+$i+"-hours"+$j).attr('checked',false);
             $("#day"+$i+"-hours"+$j).parent().find('span').eq(0).attr('style',css3);
             $("#day"+$i+"-hours"+$j).parent().find('span').eq(0).find('small').attr('style',css4);
             var init = new Switchery($("#day"+$i+"-hours"+$j));
             $("#day"+$i+"-hours"+$j).prop('checked', false); 
             $("#day"+$i+"-hours"+$j).parent().find('span').eq(1).text('Inactive');               
        }
     };
 }

function ch_label(btn){

   btn.checked == true ? 
            btn.parentNode.children[2].firstChild.nodeValue = 'Active' : 
            btn.parentNode.children[2].firstChild.nodeValue = 'Inactive';
}
```

My example
**HTML**:

```
<td>
    <label>
        <input id="day1-hours" type="checkbox" data-plugin="switchery" onclick="ch_label(this)">
        <span>Inactive</span>
    </label> 
</td>

<button id="btn">Run</button>

<td>
    <label>
        <input id="day2-hours" type="checkbox" data-plugin="switchery" checked onclick="ch_label(this)">
        <span>Active</span>
    </label> 
</td>

<button id="btn2">Run</button>
```

**JS**:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('#day1-hours');
var init = new Switchery(elem);

var elem2 = document.querySelector('#day2-hours');
var init2 = new Switchery(elem2);

$('#btn').click(function(){

    var css1 = 'background-color: rgb(100, 189, 99); border-color: rgb(100, 189, 99); box-shadow: rgb(100, 189, 99) 0px 0px 0px 16px inset; transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s, background-color 1.2s ease 0s;';
    var css2 = 'left: 20px; transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0s, left 0.2s ease 0s; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);'; 

    $('#day1-hours').attr('checked',true);
    $('#day1-hours').parent().find('span').eq(0).attr('style', css1);
    $('#day1-hours').parent().find('span').eq(0).find('small').attr('style',css2);
    var init = new Switchery($('#day1-hours'));
    $('#day1-hours').prop('checked', true);
    $('#day1-hours').parent().find('span').eq(1).html('Active');
});

$('#btn2').click(function(){

    var css3 = 'background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset; transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s;';
    var css4 = 'left: 0px; transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0s, left 0.2s ease 0s;'; 

    $('#day2-hours').attr('checked',false);
    $('#day2-hours').parent().find('span').eq(0).attr('style',css3);
    $('#day2-hours').parent().find('span').eq(0).find('small').attr('style',css4); 
    var init = new Switchery($('#day2-hours'));
    $('#day2-hours').prop('checked', false); 
    $('#day2-hours').parent().find('span').eq(1).html('Inactive');
});
```

I'm adding and removing `checked` attribute, changing `css` styling and re-initializing the plugin.

Check it

Note: you can pre-define your `css`, I've used default style. Do it in `if statement`.

Comment: it doesnt work for me sir, it turn all checkboxes to active at start and change all the value, because of the `click()` function

Comment: Did your `input` placed in `<td>` tag and inside this tag it's alone? I've found one bug, answer was updated. Show me your full content of `<td>`. Try to remove `click()`. I wanna remove it, `prop` has fixed it.

Comment: the change to your new solution and the switchify doesnt load (it load basic checkbox), i just updated the code, there's only 1 tr with 3 td inside of it with the last one contain the input checkbox, thank you for taking your time on this sir

Comment: According to your `<td>` content the code was updated a little bit. According to your basic checkbox - add to the top of `view` *cdn* from answer, what do you see?

Comment: i already add those dependency before sir, the switchery is loaded properly (css and script) it just the default value that still cannot be set from ajax. and when i try your solution the switchery goes back to basic checkbox

Comment: trying to find the solution, but it works properly for me. I see switcheries... weird

Comment: can you share your source code? i'll let you know if any differences than mine